# Create Multiple pdfs to a directory in Coldfusion

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

I am trying to create multiple pdfs and save them to a directory. I have a query based off a Appid. For each appid i need to create a pdf and store in the location. I am able to create the pdf for one appid. When I try to create pdf for more than one appid, the data is being added to the current pdf. Below is my code. Please advice as to what is going wrong here.

```
<cfquery name="getdetails" datasource="#CSTTDB#" username="#CSTTUSR#" password="#CSTTPWD#">
select a.motsid,B.APP,B.ITCONTACT,B.STD,B.ED,B.DIRECTOR,a.tool,a.upddate,a.EAQUESTION from bnsit.TBLEAMGMT a,scott.tblaccessmgmt b 
where A.MOTSID = b.motsid
and a.motsid = '16'
and a.recid = '28'
and a.EAQUESTION = 'Yes'
</cfquery>

<cfif getdetails.recordcount gt 0>
<cfloop query="getdetails"> 
<cfdocument 
     format="pdf" 
     srcfile="\\wiwauk4colddw11.itservices.sbc.com\ITUPCOMP\pdf\"     
     filename="#getdetails.motsid#_#dateformat(upddate,"mmddyy")#_eareport.pdf" 
     overwrite="yes"> 


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Emergency Access BNSIT - #getdetails.motsid#</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css" media="print">
td{ 
    width=50%;
}
.tpx td{
    border: solid 1px black;
}

</style>

<body>

<img src="email_header_plain.jpg" align="center" border= "0" alt="Header">
<p align="center">
<font size="+2" color="navy"> <strong>EMERGENCY ACCESS BNSIT</strong></font>
</p>
<br>
 <cfoutput>
<cfset timenow = dateformat(now(),'mm/dd/yyyy')>
<TABLE id="mytable" align="center" class="tpx" bgcolor="azure" border="1" width="80%">
<tr>
  <tr>
   <th  align="left"><strong>MOTSID:</strong></th>
    <th  align="left">#motsid#</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left"><strong>Application Name:</strong></th>
    <th align="left">#app#</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left"><strong>IT Contact:</strong></th>
    <th align="left">#itcontact#</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left"><strong>STD:</strong></th>
    <th align="left">#STD#</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left"><strong>Director:</strong></th>
    <th align="left">#director#</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left"><strong>ED:</strong></th>
    <th align="left">#ED#</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left"><strong>Access Provisioning Tool:</strong></th>
    <th align="left">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left"><strong>Emergency Access Tool:</strong></th>
    <th align="left">#tool#</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th align="left"><strong>Confirmation Received Date:</strong></th>
    <th align="left">#dateformat(upddate,"mm/dd/yyyy")#</th>
  </tr>
</table> 


</cfoutput>

</body>
</html>
</cfdocument>
</cfloop>

<cffile action="COPY" source="\\wiwauk4colddw11.itservices.sbc.com\ITUPCOMP\pdf\#getdetails.motsid#_#dateformat(upddate,"mmddyy")#_eareport.pdf" destination="\\135.16.235.36\devcompliance\pdfreports\"> 

  </cfif>
```

EDIT: I have updated the code above, I am trying to copy the created pdf file from one location to another server. The pdf file is being create fine in the source folder with the given naming convention.

But im am getting below error at the cffile copy. any thoughts please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
<cfdocument 
     format="pdf" 
     srcfile="\\wiwauk4colddw11.itservices.sbc.com\ITUPCOMP\pdf\"
     filename="testpdf.pdf" 
     overwrite="yes">
```

is creating a single PDF file of the name "testpdf.pdf". The contents are created within this tag, by looping over the query content.

Instead, move your `CFLOOP` to outside the `CFDOCUMENT` tag. Now, for each record, you'll create a new PDF with the content of a single record's worth of data.

**BUT**, you'll also have to change the name of the file being created to be dynamic:

```
<cfloop query="getdetails">

<cfdocument 
     format="pdf" 
     srcfile="\\wiwauk4colddw11.itservices.sbc.com\ITUPCOMP\pdf\"
     filename="testpdf_#getdetails.motsid#.pdf" 
     overwrite="yes">

     <!--- HTML content --->

</cfdocument>

</cfloop>
```

This will create a new PDF file with a name unique to each `motsid`. Otherwise, you'll just keep re-creating a single file named "testpdf.pdf" that will ultimately have the contents of the last record from the query.

Comment: Thank you so much! Initially I moved the cfloop out of the cfdocument like you said, but did not move the end tag!!!! now I did and it works thanks again!

Comment: I have the cfdocument element inside the loop and I can see only one pdf invoice in my page when I should see two. If I move the cfdocument element outside the loop then I see my two invoices in one pdf, which is not what I need.